# Bus schedule Thessaloniki - Litochoro

Tags: public-transport, buses, greece

I would like to travel to the [Mount Olympus National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Olympus) in Greece coming from Thessaloniki.

[According to the website of the national park](http://www.olympusfd.gr/us/transport.asp), it is possible to reach Litochoro both by bus and by train. I was able to find a train schedule, but fail to find the bus schedule online. Is this available somewhere?

My preference would be bus over train because the train station is rather far from the town.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the bus schedules here:
http://ktelmacedonia.gr/en/routes/list/tid=30

There seems to be one every hour at 15 minutes past the hour. The travel time is 1h15.